# Not able to upgrade from 16.04 lts to 18.04 lts

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 16.04 lts version to 18.04 lts, but the software updater always says "your system is up to date".

[image: image showing that system is up to date]

Comment: Run this command: update-manager -cd

Answer (score 15):

Upgrades from LTS releases are scheduled after the first patch - 18.04.1 which is usually a month after the first release. THey need to make sure everything goes smoothly and then the software manager will allow it.

If you're anxious, which based on my experience you shouldn't be cause there are probably tons of bugs, you can still force that upgrade, but that's not recommended.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

What I would recommend is a fresh (format) install, since anytime you upgrade you'll face incompatibility issues.

Comment: I did a `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` on an ASUS SonicMaster with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. After the upgrade, I restarted the machine, and the computer **couldn't boot** due to some infinite loops while showing messages regarding `PCI` bus. I just mention it here to help the next guy avoid such a bug/trouble.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I recommend fresh installs. Had the same issue two or three years ago.

Comment: Yes. I too faced severe problems to reboot and encountered many other software glitches, when I upgraded from 14.04.x LTS to 16.04 LTS through 'Software Updater'.

Comment: Hi @Mookey, is there a turnaround if we get such problem ?  Because I am thinking for an upgrade.